# Restrict access to virtual URI by IP address

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, dreamhost

I'm trying to get a Django application running on my shared web server (hosted with DreamHost). There's one interface I'd like to lock down based on a white-list of IP addresses, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. This interface lives at a virtual URL (in other words, there are no physical files on the server that correspond to the URL; the Django internals serve up the right thing based on the URL passed in). My shared host uses Apache as the web server, which then passes all necessary requests to Passenger.

I currently have an `.htaccess` file with the following contents in the root of my site:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/manage require_auth=true

AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
AuthName "Who Goes There?"
AuthType Basic

order deny,allow
deny from all
Satisfy any
Require user my_web_user
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

When I visit the `/manage` URL at my site, I get prompted for credentials just like I would expect. Visiting any other URL doesn't prompt me, so this rule set seems to work.

However, I can't figure out how to add the IP address white list into the mix. I'm aware that the `Satisfy any` directive is essentially a logical OR of the statements below it. Ideally, I'd like to be able to restrict access to this URL based on IP **and** require the user to login. But *only* for that particular path.

Is there something simple I'm missing here, or could the Apache / Passenger setup prevent me from being able to have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the ranges you allow with "Allow from iprange" CIDR notation works fine, so that all those which do not match will be required to authenticate.

For example:

```
AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
AuthName "Who Goes There?"
AuthType Basic
Order deny,allow
Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
Satisfy any
Require user my_web_user
```

This means that all not in range 192.168.0.0 will have to authenticate.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to require authentication even if the user comes from the white-list range.

Comment: Then remove the "Allow from"  and Satisfy any since you just want everyone to authenticate.